# Properties of the Haar measure and $\delta$-function

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, dirac-delta, haar-measure

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group. Furthermore, let $f$ denote throughout the question a continuous complex-valued function on $G$. Then the Haar measure on $G$ is a left-invariant measure, i.e.

$$\int_{G}\,\mathrm{dg}\,f(hg)=\int_{G}\,\mathrm{dg}\,f(g)$$

for all $h\in G$. First of all, I would like to ask if the Haar measure is also invariant under inversion, i.e. is it true that

$$\int_{G}\,\mathrm{dg}\,f(g^{-1})=\int_{G}\,\mathrm{dg}\,f(g)$$

Furthermore, one can introduce a $\delta$-distribution on $G$, namely by defining

$$\int_{G}\,\mathrm{dg}\,\delta(gh^{-1})f(g)=f(h)$$

Is it then true that

$$\int_{G}\,\mathrm{dg}\,\delta(hg^{-1})f(g)=\int_{G}\,\mathrm{dg}\,\delta(g^{-1})f(h^{-1}g)=\int_{G}\,\mathrm{dg}\,\delta(g)f(h^{-1}g^{-1})=f(h^{-1})?$$

Comment: The notation in the second part is misleading. The delta distribution is not regular, so you cannot write it as an integral. What is $\delta(gh^{-1})$ supposed to mean for a distribution? The answer to the first question is yes - compact topological groups are unimodular.

Comment: Yes this is just the notation as used in physics. If you want view the expression $\int_{G}\,\delta(gh^{-1})f(g)$ as a notation for $\delta_{h}(f)$.

Comment: That's what I guessed, but then $\int_G dg\,\delta(hg^{-1})f(g)$ is just $f(h)$. In any case, I find this notation really misleading here. The Dirac measure is usually not absolutely continuous with respect to the Haar measure and really has nothing to do with it (or the group structure), you can define it just as well on an arbitrary set.

Comment: Okay, the point is that in some paper I found the expression $D(g_{1},g_{2})=\int_{G}\,\mathrm{d}h\,\delta(g_{1}hg_{2}^{-1})$ for some kernel and I try to understand what it means when I insert this kernel in some integral....